# Disputed flag on what I've seen before as spam

Tags: support, spam, disputed-flags

I don't get this. My spam flag  for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60419334/top-and-bottom-of-you-guys-and-your-family-have-been-trying-g-me-know-when-you-g) (now deleted) was disputed. Why?

Posts like that were flagged as just that before, so what gives now?

The post gets deleted by a mod and I'm the bad guy.

Comment: That's not spam, it's not an advert at all.

Comment: "Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation." It does not fit this criteria. Just because they've slipped through the cracks doesn't mean yours will -- the system isn't perfect.

Comment: Note that disputed flags don't count against your flag statistics or contribute to a flag ban, so you aren't actually being punished in any way here.

Answer (score 21):

I have never seen "spam" flags get validated against a post like that. I'm…a bit surprised that you have, but nothing surprises me anymore.

Posts that are selling something or soliciting clicks (y'know, *actual spam*)? Sure. Posts that are asking you to fill out a survey, offering you a job, or other tangentially spammy things? Also sure. But a "thank you" post? No, that's not spam. Not in my eyes.

However, it *absolutely* needed to be deleted; I agree with that. It didn't even have enough information for me to consider migrating it to Meta. So I just deleted it outright.

But I don't think that it needs to be badged as spam, and I *definitely* didn't want to give that user account the penalties associated with having one of their posts nuked as spam, so I disputed the spam flags that were raised against it.

Note that spam (and rude/abusive) flags are a bit unusual in that they actually have three possible resolutions: helpful, disputed, and declined. That middle one is the unusual one. Generally, moderators cannot "dispute" flags—we can only mark them as helpful or declined. Disputed is like a middle ground that says: "well, I see what you were thinking and you were not entirely wrong to flag this, but I don't think it should be nuked as spam because I don't think the penalties should be applied". That's exactly what happened here.

So, no, you're not "the bad guy". That's not what "disputed" means.